# node multer return new file name

Tags: node.js, multer

How can i make the multer return the new filename ( `superfilename` ) for the file beeing uploaded?

so when complete, it would return the new filename as well?

server sided:

```
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '/opt/mean/public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      var datetimestamp = Date.now();
      var superfilename = file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1];
      cb(null, superfilename)
    }
  });
  var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage
  }).single('file');



  upload(req,res,function(err){

          if(err){
            res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
            return;
          }
          res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
        });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate with input and expected output and the output you are getting currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can retrun destination file name: `req.file.filename`

One way is pass the **upload** object as a middleware for your upload route as below. Rest file related information will be in your request object. You can refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) for exposed api's

```
app.post('/uploadFile',upload,(req,res)=>{

      if(req.file !==  undefined){

        // once uploaded save the user data along with uploaded photo path to the database.
        res.json({
           'fileName':req.file.originalname,
           'destination':req.file.filename,
           'userName':req.body.userName,
           'phoneNumer':req.body.phoneNumber
        });
      }else{
        res.json({
          'message':'Unable to Upload file'
        });
      }
  });
```

Comment: You don't *need* to pass it as middleware, since it exposes the `req, res, next` arguments anyway.

Comment: im going to use more in that. Anyway, without the middleware, how can i call the written filename?

Comment: you will indeed wrap your upload() code within your route app.post() so there you should be able to access `req` object.